# Unable to using toggle in jquery

Tags: jquery

My jquery:

```
$('#imgCancel').toggle(function () {
    $.each($("#List li"), function (index, item) {
        $('#menuList li').removeClass("Selected");
    });
    $('#txtName').html('');
    $('#imgAdd').show();
    $('#imgUpdate').hide();
});
}, function () {   //Eroor ---- Expect identifier or string
    $('#List li:First').addClass("Selected");
    $('#imgAdd').hide();
    $('#imgUpdate').show();
});
}
});
```

But its not a proper way to handle toggle.I got error.How to perform this task in toggle plz suggest.Thanks.

Comment: what is the error that you are getting.

Comment: What error do you get? Have you looked at the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: You got error because your code is full of syntax issues...

Comment: @Esailija  yup you have made some syntactical mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#imgCancel').toggle(function () {
    $.each($("#List li"), function (index, item) {
        $('#menuList li').removeClass("Selected");
    });
    $('#txtName').html('');
    $('#imgAdd').show();
    $('#imgUpdate').hide();
}, function () {
    $('#List li:First').addClass("Selected");
    $('#imgAdd').hide();
    $('#imgUpdate').show();
});
```

for each you can replace it by this if you want to escape the first one

```
$.each($("#List li"), function (index, item) {
        if(index != 0){
        $('this').removeClass("Selected");
}
    });
```

Comment: @ShreeKhanal Why is there an `.each()` in the first anonymous function? The code within the `.each()` function does the same thing for each iteration. Also `#List li:First` won't work, the "First" needs to not be capitalized: `#List li:first`.

Comment: @ShreeKhanal see code i have update it

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you went a bit overboard with the `})`s:

```
$('#imgCancel').toggle(//BEGIN TOGGLE

    function () {//BEGIN FIRST FUNCTION

        //the each was unnecessary since this selector uses an ID, each iteration was just selecting the same thing over and over
        $('#menuList li').removeClass("Selected");
        $('#txtName').html('');
        $('#imgAdd').show();
        $('#imgUpdate').hide();

    },//END FIRST FUNCTION

    function () {//BEGIN SECOND FUNCTION

        //notice here I changed "First" to "first", the capital F was most likely causing this line to not work properly
        $('#List li:first').addClass("Selected");
        $('#imgAdd').hide();
        $('#imgUpdate').show();

    }//END SECOND FUNCTION

);//END TOGGLE
```

Comment: +1 since this has at least some hope of working lol

Answer (score 0):

try this hopefully it will solve the syntax errors you had a redundant `});`

```
 $('#imgCancel').toggle(function () {
        $.each($("#List li"), function (index, item) {
            $('#menuList li').removeClass("Selected");
        });
        $('#txtName').html('');
        $('#imgAdd').show();
        $('#imgUpdate').hide();
    }, function () {
        $('#List li:First').addClass("Selected");
        $('#imgAdd').hide();
        $('#imgUpdate').show();    
    }
  );
```

Comment: This also has a syntax error :/